# How to extract values from metabin using R?

Tags: r, meta, r-forestplot

I’m trying to do a meta-analysis with R. After using the function metabin from the package meta, I obtain 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpTXj.png)

Here is a simplified version of my data :

```
data <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(40,25), nrow=17, ncol=8))
centres<-c("LYON","SAINT  ETIENNE","REIMS","TOULOUSE","SVP","NANTES","STRASBOURG","GRENOBLE","ANGERS","TOULON","MARSEILLE","COLMAR","BORDEAUX","RENNES","VALENCE","CAEN","NANCY")
rownames(data) = centres
colnames(data) = c("case_exposed","witness_exposed","case_nonexposed","witness_nonexposed","exposed","nonexposed","case","witness")
metabin( data$case_exposed, data$case, data$witness_exposed, data$witness, studlab=centres,
       data=data, sm="OR")
```

I would like to only extract the values of OR and 95%-CI in the fixed effect model and the random effects model, so I could put them in another array. Is there anyway this is possible ?

I tried to use summary, but it doesn’t change anything.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data and the code you are running. Picture of data or output aren't particularly helpful. Also, please give the desired output so possible solutions can be tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example:

```
library(meta)
data(Olkin95)
meta1 <- metabin(event.e, n.e, event.c, n.c,
                 data = Olkin95, subset = c(41, 47, 51, 59),
                 method = "Inverse")
summary(meta1)
```

The estimated RR (with 95% CI) from the fixed and random models are

```
Number of studies combined: k = 4

                         RR           95%-CI     z  p-value
Fixed effect model   0.4407 [0.2416; 0.8039] -2.67   0.0075
Random effects model 0.4434 [0.2038; 0.9648] -2.05   0.0403
```

You can extract these values using:

```
(est.fixed <- unlist(summary(meta1)$fixed))

          TE         seTE        lower        upper            z            p        level 
-0.819414226  0.306710201 -1.420555173 -0.218273278 -2.671623649  0.007548526  0.950000000

(RR.fixed <- exp(est.fixed[1]))

       TE 
0.4406897 

(CI.fixed <- exp(c(est.fixed[1]-1.96*est.fixed[2],est.fixed[1]-1.96*est.fixed[2])))

       TE        TE 
0.2415772 0.2415772
```

Similarly for the random effect model:

```
(est.random <- unlist(summary(meta1)$random))
         TE        seTE       lower       upper           z           p       level          df 

-0.81325423  0.39665712 -1.59068790 -0.03582057 -2.05027011  0.04033808  0.95000000          NA 

(RR.random <- exp(est.random[1]))

       TE 
0.4434127 

(CI.random <- exp(c(est.random[1]-1.96*est.random[2],est.random[1]+1.96*est.random[2])))

       TE        TE 
0.2037825 0.9648272
```

Comment: Thank you very much Marco Sandri ! It works perfectly ! But I was wondering from where those formula come from ?

Comment: It is the formula that connects the beta coefficients of a logistic regression to the ORs: ORs= exp(betas). https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35013/exponentiated-logistic-regression-coefficient-different-than-odds-ratio